# Showing that left and right group actions of group $G $ on set $A$ induce the same equivalence relation on A?

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations, group-actions

> Let $g.a$ denote the left action of group $G$ on a set $A \; \forall
> g\in G , a\in A$. Let $a.g$ denote the corresponding right action of $G$ on $A$. Then show that both induce the same equivalence relation on A.
>
> Define $\sim, \sim'$ on A as : $\forall a,b \in A$
>
> $a \sim b \iff \exists g\in G \ni a=g.b$
>
> $a \sim' b \iff \exists g \in G \ni a=b.g$

I want to show $a\sim b \iff a\sim' b$

These clearly both are indeed equivalence relation.

Suppose $a\sim b$ then $\exists g \in G \ni a=g.b$ but how do I use this to show $a=b.g' $ for some $g' \in G$?

What am I missing? Help is appreciated.

Comment: Is $A$ a group? What does it mean to be the "corresponding" right action of $G$ on $A$. In other words I don't understand why the left and right action have to be related.

Comment: No, A is any set. I am not sure but corresponding probably means that the way G acts on A will be preserved